# For loop not being executed C

Tags: c

I am trying to scan any ports that are open and saving those which are in text file. The program displays the first loop ( checking whether or not the arguments are correct) but for some reason skips the entire for loop. I am a newbie in c so any help is much appreciated

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define HTTP_PORT 80

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    int sockfd=0;
    int min = atoi(argv[1]);
    int max = atoi(argv[2]);
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    struct hostent *url;

    for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
    {
        printf("%d, is %s\n",i,argv[i]);
    }

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (sockfd < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Failed to open socket\n");
        return 1;
    }

    url = gethostbyname(argv[3]); /* does not support IP6 */
    if (url == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Host not found\n");
        return 2;
    }

    printf("Scanning ports %d - %d\n",  min, max);

    FILE * file = fopen("/home/llp2/Desktop/Assignment/ports.txt", "w");//open log file

    for (unsigned short port = min; port < max; port++)//loop through and scan all ports
    {
            memset(&serv_addr, 0, sizeof(serv_addr));
            serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
            memcpy(&serv_addr.sin_addr, url->h_addr, url->h_length);
            serv_addr.sin_port = htons(HTTP_PORT);

        /* Connect to the server */
        if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) > 0) 
        {   
                //if the port is open get information about that port and print it to the log file
                char host[128];
                char service[128];
                getnameinfo((struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof serv_addr, host, (sizeof host), service, sizeof service, 0);
                printf("Port : %d, Service : %s, Open\n", port, service);
                fprintf(file, "Port : %d, Service : %s, Open\n", port, service);
        }

        close(sockfd);
    }

        fclose(file);//Close the file

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Print your loop conditions before the loop, such as `min`, and make sure they are what you think they are. That's one of the very few ways a loop won't actually execute.

Comment: The min and max values are fine as the printf, prints out the relevant data

Comment: Also, `fopen()` can fail. You should check `file`. Not your problem, but it can *become* a problem.

Comment: Shouldn't your first 2 use of fprintf be printf instead? That way you will see the error that is being triggered.

Comment: i am inputting a small range of ports (Ex. 0-34) and the hostname. 
the observed output until the for loop is as expected printing the values in argv. I expected the forloop to loop through the range of ports and write the ones found open in a file. Instead, the loop is skipped and the program ends

Comment: Put a print statement at the start of the second loop, making sure it ends with a newline.  Rerun the code.  Then let us know if it still doesn't run.  Add `printf("Scanning port %d\n", port);` before `memset(&serv_addr, 0, sizeof(serv_addr));`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are crashing on a segmentation fault when I run you code as follows:

```
g++ code.cpp
./a.out 1000 2000 localhost
```

For starters, you are closing the socket on every iteration of the for loop.  When you attempt to close it a second time, you are probably going to get undefined results:

This line:

```
    close(sockfd);
}
```

I suspect you want to create a new socket on every iteration of the loop.

Further, if the file fails to open, the fclose(file) call will crash as well.

This line:

```
fclose(file);//Close the file
```

Should be this:

```
if (file)
{
    fclose(file);
    file = NULL;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for noticing, I arranged the line but the loop is still being skipped :/

Comment: The loop is not being skipped. It's just crashing within the loop.  Add more print statement throughout your code.

Comment: @Chanter08 - updated. If the file fails to open, the `fclose` call will crash.

Answer (score 1):

Three things:

First, since you a separate connection on each iteration of the loop, you need to create the socket in the loop.  So move the call to `socket` inside the second `for` loop, just before the call to `connect`.

Second, take a look at where you're connecting:

```
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(HTTP_PORT);
```

You connect to port 80 every time through the loop.  If the `connect` fails the loop doesn't print anything, whether to the file or to the screen.  So if port 80 is not open, you won't see anything get printed.

Change this to connect to the port you want to scan:

```
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
```

Third, you're not checking the proper return value for `connect`.  It returns 0 on success and -1 on error.  You're checking if the return value is greater than 0.  This is always false.  So change it to check for 0:

```
if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) == 0)
```